# Attribute of Editor class can't be found through reflection

Tags: android, debugging, reflection, colors, text-cursor

I'm using an emulator with Android API 28 x86, and my project target/compile SDK version is 28. With this in mind, I can proceed to the real problem.

I'm trying to change the color of the EditText cursor at runtime using reflection. Looking through the SDK 28 files, I found the name of the Field that I want to change, and it is "mDrawableForCursor", this field exists inside of the Editor class. I don't know why, but this class can't be referred to my project, but that's not a problem, I can get a reference of it through reflection too. So, I wrote the following code

```
    // Get the cursor resource id
    Field field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    int drawableResId = field.getInt(this._inputEditText);
    field.setAccessible(false);

    // Get the editor
    field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object editor = field.get(this._inputEditText);
    field.setAccessible(false);

    // Get the drawable and set a color filter
    Drawable cursorPipe = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), drawableResId);
    cursorPipe.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable[] drawables = {cursorPipe, cursorPipe};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        field = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDrawableForCursor"); // error
    } else {
        field = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
    }
```

Now, weird things start to happen... I put one breakpoint at Editor object, and found that field exist in there (the last one), but when my code try to get this field by the method getDeclaredField(), an Exception is thrown

> No field mDrawableForCursor in class Landroid/widget/Editor; (declaration of 'android.widget.Editor' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)

[image: editor debugging]

Just for curiosity, I got all declared fields of this Editor class and it seems to have only eight available, and now I have no idea of what is happening in my code. [image]

Comment: Starting with P, they're locking down on certain uses of reflection. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I read the link and it seems impossible to change through reflection now.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. FYI: To who want to change edit text cursor, use xml instead of reflection `android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/your_xml"`